# Insert text with vi editor

Tags: vi

I was using `nano` before.

I'm a bit confused on how to start inserting text, sometimes I just start typing and on the bottom I see `-- insert --` and I can edit and save fine. But sometimes I just skip around without being able to go in edit mode, what is going on?

Comment: Hint: Install *Vim* and run `vimtutor`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To insert text into vi or vim, you need to enter *Insert Mode*. Do this by pressing <kbd>i</kbd>.

Alternatively, press <kbd>a</kbd> to append, for example. Press <kbd>o</kbd> to insert text below the current line.

Once you're done, press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to leave the insert mode again.

There are [lots of vi/vim commands](https://www.cs.colostate.edu/helpdocs/vi.html) for simple text manipulation, maybe print out a cheatsheet and try to learn the most important ones.

[image: vi/vim Cheat Sheet]

Comment: This is a good reference later on.

Answer (score 1):

If you are in normal mode, pres the "i" key to go to insert mode. The escape key takes you back to normal mode.

Answer (score 0):

`vi` and `vim` are completely different from `nano`. With `nano`, you are able to use keyboard shortcuts to save files, open new ones and access other "non-text editing" functionality. `vi`/`vim` are different because they are ***modal***: there is an ***Insert*** mode (which you have reached by accident) and a ***Normal*** mode. Insert Mode is equivalent to the normal functionality of an editor like `nano`, and Normal mode is specifically dedicated to commands. For example, to save a file in `vim` you enter `:w` (for **w**rite) in Normal mode.

I would suggest looking up and reading a `vim` tutorial. After running through the basics, you can start to digest the breadth and depth of `vim` functionality by looking at tips and cheatsheets. Definitely learn the basics first, though!